# Impulse travelling on line animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I want to recreate the video animation in the background of the [Uber Developer webpage]([link](https://developer.uber.com/)) programatically using JavaScript/CSS.

I am defining a grid of paths (my own design, not the one on the aforemnetioned page) on my page using Canvas lines and am trying to figure how to get the effect of light-pulse-through-optic-fiber effect to propagate signals on randomly selected paths in my grid.

Here is a sample of the canvas background I'm working on (unfinished) -
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4qtFMwHzSBxYzF5bHhnTVF2UzQ/view?usp=sharing)

I am trying for the pulse to propagate from one black end point to the other along the form of the segment connecting them and converge / diverge at junctions.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Any frameworks that can be of help?

Comment: Can you show the grid you have currently implemented? That can help find some methods for you.

Comment: CSS animation can be done for this. If you can give me a grid to work on, you can wait for this method from me. As the video background grid is totally random, I am not sure about the grid you need.

Comment: I keep getting some weird error when I try to edit the question to upload the image. Here is a image link to a sample of the grid - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4qtFMwHzSBxYzF5bHhnTVF2UzQ/view . (I'm still working on getting the full thing into canvas, will update in an hour with the same)

Comment: Edited the question with relevant information

Answer (score 0):

Try performing the path in SVG and cheer with [lazy painter](http://lazylinepainter.info/). The advantages are many as it is cargo weight is minimal and is cross browser compatible.

Comment: Thanks. But this still leaves the issue of getting that glowing leading point effect.